# htaccess redirect with complete url

Tags: .htaccess

I have two links that need redirection:

```
https://mywebsite.com/countries
https://mywebsite.com.ar/countries
```

both of these links need to redirect to another page.

I know I can do this way in my .htaccess, but both links end with `/countries`:

```
Redirect 301 /countries http://mynewurl.com/countries
```

Is it possible to check the whole path that I want to redirect or at least `.com` and `.ar` and set those differences in my .htaccess

I tried this too, but doesn't seem to work properly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mywebsite.com.ar/countries
RewriteRule (.*) https://mynewurl.com.ar/countries/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mywebsite\.(com\.ar)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^countries(/.*)?$ https://mynewurl.%1/$0 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand, how this can redirect based on (.com) or (.ar) to their related pages.

Comment: nope, `https://mywebsite.com/countries` will redirect to `http://mynewurl.com/countries` and `https://mywebsite.com.ar/countries` will redirect to `http://mynewurl.com.ar/countries`

Comment: Hope it worked now. Otherwise tell me what wrong redirect URL do you get and what was expected?